# boot from USB drive Ubuntu or Windows 8

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, usb

As security I would like only when I have the USB drive plugged in the laptop to be ask if I would like to boot my Ubuntu desktop otherwise to boot my installer Windows 8 . Could anyone let me know if is possible.
Regards Cosmin

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to install Ubuntu on the HDD (partitions for `/` and `swap`, maybe also `/home` or whatever you want to separate), but create a separate `/boot` partition on the USB drive and also install the GRUB bootloader there.

You then should be able to plug in your USB and select it as boot device from your BIOS/UEFI menu.

But the other partitions would remain on the HDD and could be accessed from the Windows system (using special tools) or any other live (Ubuntu) system booting from CD/DVD or USB. Drive encryption would be useful then to prevent that kind of unwanted access, although I am not sure whether this would work together with booting from an external media.

Note that I never tried this kind of installation, so I have no practical experience and might tell you something wrong.

**Make sure you have valid backups of your data before changing anything!**
And as always: you operate *on your own risk*. Nobody on AU can be made responsible for possible damage to your machine or data.

Comment: You sound like a lawyer instead of an engineer!  :P  ;-) (upvoted as I would have said the exact same thing, except use an SLC  stick)